# android:imeOptions="actionNext" does not work without specifying android:inputType

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview

Code:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_uname"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:popupBackground="#aaaaaa"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_page_text_size" />
```

in above code when i don't specify android:inputType="text" "Next Button" Does not appear on the keyboard
Android OS: 4.0.1

Answer (score 3):

single line deprecated so need inputtype add below code.

```
         android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about android:imeOptions not android:imeActionLabel which (as its name indicates) is a label, this is what will be wrote on the button...

Answer (score -1):

Use imeActionLabel instead of imeOptions as follow..

android:inputType="text"

android:imeActionLabel="Next"

Comment: @Entretoize  android:inputType="text" AND android:imeActionLabel="Next" these two line work as action as label. NEXT-focuses on next view and DONE closes the keyboard.